# Finding vector opposite to another?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, vector

I need to know how to find a vector opposite to another, but the second vector is not necessarily the same magnitude as the first, but the direction is opposite. Ex:

I made a small diagram :)
[alt text http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/5394/prettydiagram.png](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/5394/prettydiagram.png)

Basically if I have the coordinates of A(-150,150) and I want B to be opposite, and have a magnitude of only 2, I would want to obtain B(-200,-150). What I am doing is making an application that can draw cubic bezier shapes and I noticed with lots of these, there are bezier handles and modifying one handle cause the other one to move too. How could this be done?

Thanks

Comment: I am a bit confused about the origin. You see, vectors and line segments are not the same thing. Vectors start at origin. You need 2 vectors to represent a directional line segment.

Comment: Hm. Is that diagram correct? I don't understand the coordinates you've listed, nor what you mean by magnitude of 2 (or 4).

Comment: I assume it is a relative scale.

Comment: in my application units are pixels

Comment: See my last comment on your answer, I have those pieces of information and need to find the coordinates of B based on that

Comment: Rotating A 180 degrees around red dot works, but I need to account for the length of red dot to B being different from length red dot to A

Comment: Don't use links that just redirect you to a signup page for some useless service noone want to sign up for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple, really.

`B = -1/2 * A`, or `B.x = -1/2 * A.x`, `B.y = -1/2 * A.y`, `B.z = -1/2 * A.z`. This talks about vectors, btw. You would want to shift the result. The formula is dead-simple. What am I missing?

***EDIT***

Your app knows the red dot location (let's abbreviate it as R vector). Your app also knows the A vector. It needs to find the B vector that is on the same line as AR, on the other side of R  as A, and such as A is twice as far than B. Well, in that case:

- Temporarily calculate vector `V = (A - R)`
- Now (It is simple :) ): `B = R - 0.5 * V`.

It is that simple, I promise. The capital letters represent vectors, which are generally 2-tuples or 3-tuples of real numbers (depending on whether you work in 2D or 3D).

There is not much to this, really. Any questions?

Comment: What do you mean by shift the results?

Comment: @Jex Since you already know A and B, are you trying to find the coordinate of a red dot? I am confused.

Comment: @Jex, if you have a directional line segment from `(2,3)` to `(9,-6)`, then it is really the vector `(7, -9)` shifted by vector `(2,3)` - meaning that you would pretend that `(2,3)` is the origin.

Comment: No, assuming I do not know B, I was thinking of rotating A around the red dot 180 degs but this does not make it smaller or larger.

Comment: @Jex, what are the coordinates of a red dot?

Comment: does it matter, its just an arbitrary example,but in my program I'd know it

Comment: my application knows red dot, and A, and knows length Red Dot to A and Length Red dot to B

Answer (score 5):

All you have to do is calculate the unit vector of the original vector by dividing each component by the magnitude of the vector and then apply a rotational transformation about a 180 degree angle.

The rotational transformation matrix looks like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [equationsheet.com](http://www.equationsheet.com/latexrender/pictures/46befe367f1c80ac00351de7785fd439.gif))</sub>

Apply the transformation like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [equationsheet.com](http://www.equationsheet.com/latexrender/pictures/78c27d415d755a0be04e4747da351a09.gif))</sub>

The primed vector is now the unit vector pointing in the direction you want.  You can scale it by any magnitude you wish.

In your special case the angle is 180 degrees.  You know that the cosine of 180 is -1 and the sine is zero, so the matrix is simple:

[image]
<sub>(source: [equationsheet.com](http://www.equationsheet.com/latexrender/pictures/3c16fd7210502fe391688e89f9b23589.gif))</sub>

This makes it clear as day:  All you have to do is reverse the signs of the two unit vector components and you have your answer.

Comment: -1 for making something ridiculously simple look complicated.

Comment: Just giving the background story for those who might be interested.  Agreed, it's not complicated, but the back story allows you to understand how to handle the general case.  It's only complicated to people who don't know vectors and are frightened of mathematics.